# Why do I get empty lines wtih f.write?

Tags: python, io

My code

```
sel=[]
for x in range(67):
    sel.append(x)
i=0
fnew=open('data.txt', 'w')
f=open('DATATESTKAREN.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if i in sel:
        fnew.write("%s\n" % line)
    i+=1
```

What I get is not what I really want
 FORMAT:           OCCAM2MTDATA_1.0

```
 MODEL RESPONSE FROM KAREN

 sites:          15

 site-6

 site-7

 site-5
```

How should I reformat my `write`?

Comment: You are using `\n`... ?

Comment: @Idos Yes,thanks ,now works fine.

Comment: the line from `f.readlines()` includes the `\n` in the file, no need to add your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `readlines` automatically add a `new line` (`\n`) to the end of each line.

In your code you call `fnew.write("%s\n" % line)`, so you add another one.

If you just use `fnew.write("%s" % line)` you will be fine!

Note: I would suggest to use `.format()` instead of `%s`, as its the "newer" and suggested way, but in your case you just just simply use the variable for writing: `fnew.write(line)`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gábor Erdős in regards the extra `'\n'`

It also seems that you want to only read the first 68 lines (counter 0 to 67), which means you can simplify your code a bit:

```
i=0
limit = 67
with open('data.txt', 'w') as fnew:
    with open('DATATESTKAREN.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if i <= limit:
                fnew.write(line)
                i += 1
            else:
                break  # no need to read more lines
```

HTH,
Edwin.